# How to Paste desired selection in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a problem, I was wondering is there a way of inserting the (ID VALUES) to each column since I forgot. I have a really long code. Is there a way for me to select a piece of code to paste the number ID values or a Method of some sort? Or is my only option to do it manually?

```
CREATE TABLE tASTON
(AsM_ID int Primary Key Not Null IDENTITY(1,1),Make Nvarchar(50), Model nvarchar (50)) 

Insert into tASTON(AsM_ID,Make,Model) Values ('Aston Martin','DB4')
Insert into tASTON (AsM_ID,Make,Model) Values ('Aston Martin','DB5')
Insert into tASTON (AsM_ID,Make,Model) Values ('Aston Martin','DB6')
Insert into tASTON (AsM_ID,Make,Model) Values ('Aston Martin','DB7')
Insert into tASTON (AsM_ID,Make,Model) Values ('Aston Martin','Vanquish') etc...
```

Comment: It's an identity you can insert a value in it

Comment: I suspect @Seripton meant "Cannot". Remove AsM_ID from the `INSERT INTO` part of the statement, and your command ought to work.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing it's an `IDENTITY` column, there's no need to manually `INSERT` values. This ought to work:

```
Insert into tASTON(Make,Model) Values ('Aston Martin','DB4')
```

Update: Removed `brand`, as it was confusing and a mistake on my part. Replaced `Brand` with `Make`, instead.*

Unrelated, but judging by the name of the table, are you really creating one table per brand of car? If so, I'd suggest creating a `make` and a `car` table, where you then implement a key relationship between tCar and tMake:

```
CREATE TABLE tCAR
(
    CAR_ID int Primary Key Not Null IDENTITY(1,1)
    , MAKE_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tMake(MAKE_ID)
    , Model nvarchar (50)
)
```

Comment: Oh so for the table tcar I just input all the car makes only? and for the tbrand table how would I go about that for each car model?

Comment: @user3753188 - You'd create 1 row in the brand table per brand. I.e. `Aston Martin` will get `brand_id` 1 in the brand table, `Chevrolet` gets `brand_id` 2 (`brand-id` would be another `IDENTITY` column). 

That way, rather than repeating the brand name every time, you'd insert the ID number for the brand, and then the model. (I mistakenly had make in the table script before. I just corrected that, as that would be replaced with the `brand` (or `make`) table.